# Why getting error failed to parse pom?

Tags: java, apache, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

while building project via jenkins getting below error.

> Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinProject
>   Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.3/apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.zip to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven on Jenkins
>   ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\apache-maven-3.5.3 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\apache-maven-3.5.3.__rename
>       at hudson.FilePath$29.invoke(FilePath.java:2107)
>       at hudson.FilePath$29.invoke(FilePath.java:2100)

Comment: can you check what files are there at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\apache-maven-3.5.3` location

Comment: file is present at that location: Bin, Boot, cofig, lic folder and license, notice files are prsent